# How to uninstall apps in android programmatically with PackageInstaller

Tags: android, android-9.0-pie, uninstallation

I have created a simple android uninstaller app that helps to remove multiple apps at once. I use this code to accomplish this task:

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", app.getPackageName(), null);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_UNINSTALL_PACKAGE, uri);
// store result
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_RETURN_RESULT, true);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

But now, according to this [android doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_UNINSTALL_PACKAGE), `ACTION_UNINSTALL_PACKAGE` is deprecated in API level 29 and it's recommended to use `PackageInstaller.uninstall(String, IntentSender)` instead. I want to use this new api but I can't find any good example on how this is implemented.
Any help is appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to this link

https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=android.content.pm.PackageInstaller

and implement like this -

```
@Override
public void uninstall(String packageName, String callerPackageName, int flags, IntentSender statusReceiver, int userId) throws RemoteException {
boolean success = VAppManagerService.get().uninstallPackage(packageName);
if (statusReceiver != null) {
    final Intent fillIn = new Intent();
    fillIn.putExtra(PackageInstaller.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME, packageName);
    fillIn.putExtra(PackageInstaller.EXTRA_STATUS, success ? PackageInstaller.STATUS_SUCCESS : PackageInstaller.STATUS_FAILURE);
    fillIn.putExtra(PackageInstaller.EXTRA_STATUS_MESSAGE, PackageHelper.deleteStatusToString(success));
    fillIn.putExtra("android.content.pm.extra.LEGACY_STATUS", success ? 1 : -1);
    try {
        statusReceiver.sendIntent(mContext, 0, fillIn, null, null);
    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Sure.  Thank you